# Create and Search user posts in PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

This is my first entry into backend development, taking mostly a design role in past projects.  Im working on a personal project and have fleshed out  what I feel is a logic of sorts. Just a few very basic user tasks broken down.

**Core User Actions**:

- A user can create a new posting

  A user can find posts from other users by tag, date created, and
  other content. This is done in kinda a central search area.  (Search
  string: "Dog Saddle", retrieves posts with mentions of dog saddels,
  dogs, and saddels)

  A post's creator can be contacted from the post.

  A user can delete their created posts.

**I need guidance/suggestions with the following:**

What data should I capture for users?
What framework is best for the application dynamics I've described? (ROR, Python, PHP ect. I'm a one man team currently)

Are there open source projects I may gain reference from?

I'm very dedicated to learning on my own, and can make use of good advice!

Thanks,

Comment: You are building a forum? blog? or something simpler? The requirements you list sound like the features found in several types of projects. Is there any example of something that you have found that is similar to what you are trying to create?

Comment: I'm trying to build a minimal classifieds style site. Kinda like craigslist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the rather generic requirements you've outlined and that you are just entering into the development arena, you should try an established framework. That way you won't need to write everything from scratch. You'll still have plenty of control, but the benefits of many commonly used functions, classes etc that will speed up your development.

Give something like CodeIgniter for PHP a try. See http://codeigniter.com/. There are a lot of tutorials online to help you get started. For example, see http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/.

What you've described doesn't suggest a particular language at all. ROR, Python, PHP--you could use any of those to create what you've described. PHP is considered by many to have a less steep learning curve than ROR and Python, which is why I recommended it. However, there are frameworks for these other languages as well that will give you the same benefits as code igniter.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, thank you TechnoTarek! I'm going to mess around with codeigniter to see if I can bring this idea to fruition.